# How to change column type to string uppercase in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

Is there any way to set up a string to uppercase in the migration file? I have some IDs that need to be saved as uppercase in the database.

```
class CreateIds < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :Ids do |t|
      t.string :ID1  --- something like t.string.upcase?
      t.string :ID2
      t.string :ID3
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would imagine you would handle that in the model, not in the migration.

Comment: you can also create a `rake task` that will uppercase all the existing IDs in the database

Comment: Oh, also, `ID1` (etc.) is not a very ruby-ish attribute name. Consider, instead, `id_1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using your migration. You need to handle that using your model before_save method.

In essence  your migration will look like below. Normal Ruby migration.

```
class CreateIds < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :Ids do |t|
      t.string :ID1
      t.string :ID2
      t.string :ID3
    end
  end
end
```

So your model will look like the below

```
class Ids < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save :uppercase_fields

   def uppercase_fields
      self.ID1.uppercase!
   end
end
```

What the function does is before you save a record it converts the ID1 field to uppercase and stores the uppercase value to the table.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`t.string` creates a VARCHAR type column. "Uppercase text type columns" is not really a thing. At least not in any DB I know of.

If you want to coerce a attribute into uppercase you can do it by overriding the setter:

```
class ScreamyThing < ApplicationRecord
  def name=(value)
    super(value.upcase)
  end

  def hello
    "HELLO MY NAME IS #{name}!!!"
  end
end

puts ScreamyThing.new.hello
# => "HELLO MY NAME IS FOO!!!"
```